# Is this PSU configuration correct for dual power rails and a virtual ground?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, dual-supply

I am pretty new to electronics, and I am just not understanding if I have the right configuration on my Tektronix PS2502g PSU. I am trying to supply voltage to a LM741 op-amp but do not appear to be successful with various different outputs I was trying to achieve. Same with an ICL8038 function generator IC - output is anything but a square, tri, or sine wave. So I was thinking maybe I am powering it wrong. I have included a diagram showing my PSU configuration - output 2 is controlling output 1.

I am using series tracking mode, which is diagrammed in the image per the PSU manual. The bottom schematic is how I imagine +,-, and virtual ground would be achieved in a generic opamp circuit based on other posts from this stack and other websites. Links available if needed.

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: For your "circuit" image, which is output 1 and which is output 2?

Comment: (also, that's a true ground, not a virtual ground. Well, it's not an earth ground, but it's certainly not a virtual ground.)

Comment: @Hearth left would be O2, right would be O1.

Comment: @Integration Okay, that should probably be noted as it's opposite what you used before. If the outputs are in the same order as they're shown above, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Hearth what would we expect the output voltage from the linked - + highlighted in green? Im starting to think that there may be something wrong with my PSU. Thanks

Comment: @Integration The voltage on that relative to what? Voltage is a measurement between two points; only voltage differences have meaning.

Comment: @Hearth relative to the either the positive rail or negative rail. I would expect it to be 0 relative to +5 and -5, but I am pretty new to this. Also, regarding the image discrepancy, I will modify mage and update.

Comment: @Integration Relative to the positive rail, it will be -10 V, and relative to the negative rail it will be +10 V.

Comment: @Hearth thanks, I am going to go validate that. Appreciate the assistance so far